# Conditional adjustment to poorly formatted 12-hour time data

Tags: r, time, conditional-statements, data-cleaning

I have a timeseries of 'Detection' data. The time format uses a 12-hour clock and a preceeding 'A' or 'P' to denote AM or PM. Where the 12-hour clock has double digits (10, 11, 12) the preceeding 'A' or 'P' is not followed by a space character (the file separator). This means that times are not read correctly so the time data is combined into the AM.PM column and the Detection data shifts a column to the left. See example dataset below.

For all double-digit hours, I want to separate the A or P character from the time data and put the data in their respective columns.

I have tried doing this by conditionally inserting a space character but I haven't been able to move the data back into their proper place. I would be very grateful for any advice or solutions to this, thank you!

```
df <- data.frame(AM.PM  = c("P", "P", "P10:00:00.943", "P10:00:01.994"),
                 Time = c("9:59:59.862", "9:59:59.862", "[7307455B02]", "[800750CD02]"),
                 Detection = c("[800750CD02]", "[7507455B02]", "", ""))
```

The current output:

```
          AM.PM         Time    Detection
1             P  9:59:59.862 [800750CD02]
2             P  9:59:59.862 [7507455B02]
3 P10:00:00.943 [7307455B02]             
4 P10:00:01.994 [800750CD02]
```

The desired output:

```
          AM.PM         Time    Detection
1             P   9:59:59.862 [800750CD02]
2             P   9:59:59.862 [7507455B02]
3             P  10:00:00.943 [7307455B02]             
4             P  10:00:01.994 [800750CD02]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the rows where `AM.PM` column has value which is more than one character you can split the column into 2 and rename the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

inds <- nchar(df$AM.PM) > 1

df[inds, ] <- df[inds, ]  %>%
                extract(AM.PM, c('AM.PM', 'Time1'), '(.)(.*)') %>%
                select(AM.PM, Time = Time1, Detection = Time)

df

#  AM.PM         Time    Detection
#1     P  9:59:59.862 [800750CD02]
#2     P  9:59:59.862 [7507455B02]
#3     P 10:00:00.943 [7307455B02]
#4     P 10:00:01.994 [800750CD02]
```

`extract` divides the column into two, first column keeps only the first character whereas second column consists of everything else.

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak! This is very neat and works perfectly with my much larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way. It relies on having just one alphabetic character as AM-PM marker in the first column and in having `"["` in the wrong place, meaning, column 2.

```
i <- grep("\\[", df$Time)
df$Detection[i] <- df$Time[i]
df$Time[i] <- substring(df$AM.PM[i], 2)
df$AM.PM[i] <- substring(df$AM.PM[i], 1, 1)

df
#  AM.PM         Time    Detection
#1     P  9:59:59.862 [800750CD02]
#2     P  9:59:59.862 [7507455B02]
#3     P 10:00:00.943 [7307455B02]
#4     P 10:00:01.994 [800750CD02]
```

Comment: Thanks Rui! Works perfectly and its really great to have a base R option here.